# Caching gzipped responses from Node/Express/Redis

Tags: node.js, caching, express, redis

My requirement is to generate reports on a daily basis which several users access.
The data only changes every 24 hours.
Currently I use Node to create the report from data stored in Redis and generate the response which is compressed using Express's Compress() method.
Creating and zipping these responses takes about 40 seconds (the response is about 4MB of JSON uncompressed)
My preference would be to cache/store these responses either on the filesystem or in memory for a certain period of time.
I don't want to implement Varnish or other reverse proxy just for this, so can anyone suggest another approach to effectively cache the responses?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps [`express-view-cache`](https://npmjs.org/package/express-view-cache) is useful?

Comment: Thanks Robert, that looks like it does what I am looking for but the author says it isn't Production ready so I'm reluctant to commit to it. I've read a few other solutions where they suggest caching the gzipped response in the Compressed Buffer but I haven't seen any examples of anyone doing this. Can you comment?

Comment: Not sure what they mean by 'Compressed Buffer'. If you post some links I'll take a look at it.

Comment: If you look [at this link:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12591861/json-zip-response-in-node-js) the last answer cites the zlib docs which have a comment stating that gzipping responses is expensive and that they should be _"cache the Compressed Buffer"_. That's what i'm wondering about. Many thanks, Colm

Comment: Ah right, it means that it makes more sense to cache the compressed response instead of caching an uncompressed response and compress that every time it's being sent back to the client. Anyway, the 'not ready for production' warning for `express-view-cache` seems to be only related for the memory-caching part, but it also seems to support Redis (which you already have running)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recently had to do something similar, where I received a large JSON payload from a MongoDB database intended to be sent to a user application.

I only needed to update it periodically, about every 10 minutes, but GZipping the response took serious time, so I periodically grab the data, gzip it, and store it away, sending it in this example as a response to a GET request.

```
var zlib = require('zlib');
var Buffer = require('buffer').Buffer;
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var yourData, cachedGzip;

// zlib performs gzip compression, passes payload to callback asynchronously
zlib.gzip(new Buffer(yourData)), function(err, data){
    cachedGzip = data
});

// Somewhere later in your app...
// Can now use the cached data for gzip responses, example route
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  res.header('Content-Encoding', 'gzip');
  res.send(cachedGzip);
});
```